# Why does the installation of xdebug on my Mac not work?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, xdebug, pecl

I installed PHP with Homebrew using `brew install php`.

`php -v` gives me:

```
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2021 17:21:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

So PHP is installed successfully and is also running as a service with `brew services start php`.

To install xdebug I use the command `pecl install xdebug` which seems to work right, but at the end I get the message:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so'

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/pecl/20200930
```

The install instruction from the install doc xdebug.org did not help. I tried to create an directory 99-xdebug.ini (which was not created by the install command) in the php directory and edit the php.ini file to add zend_extension=xdebug. But this did not work after restarting the Webserver and php service, php was still not shown with xdebug (`php -v`).

I am using Macbook 13 2017 with no Touch Bar and Big Sur.

Edit:
I removed pecl from the director and now the installation worked fine. But now I have the following problem when using `php-v`

```
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20200930/xdebug.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2021 17:21:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar error to "ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.9/pecl/20200930".

For me, the directory was a link:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 rsimmons  admin  23 Jul 26 11:53 /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.21/pecl -> /usr/local/lib/php/pecl
```

However, `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl` did not exist  - so I created it:

`$ mkdir /usr/local/lib/php/pecl`

and reran `pecl install xdebug`

and the install worked.

Comment: Spent quite some time searching before finding your post that solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.  I found the same answer in a number of other places but this is the clearest and simplest explanation and fix.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem by uninstalling xdebug and php. I made sure that no conf files or directories where left. I removed the php directory containing the php.ini with rm -rf.

Than I just reinstalled php with brew. Before installing xdebug I checked if the pecl file was existing which was causing the problem in the first place (made sure It did not exist) than reinstalled xdebug with pecl. And no errors came while installing xdebug. php -v gave me the perfect response that I wanted. I guess the problem was the pecl file in the first place disturbing the clean installation of xdebug and causing all this problems.

```
PHP 8.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 26 2021 15:36:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```